# How many ways to select a subset of eight doughnuts from three types of doughnuts if at most two doughnuts of the first type can be chosen?

Tags: combinatorics

Please check my answer

I start by find all possible case that we can choose doughnuts without concern the condition

$$\binom{(8+3-1)}{8} = \binom{10}{8}$$

then  I consider the case that fit the condition

Um,I'm not sure about find directly I choose to find by only the ways to doughtnuts by exclude fist type instead  that is

$$\binom{(8+2-1)}{8} = \binom{9}{8}$$

then the set of th way to pick doughtnuts that fit the condition is

$$\binom{10}{8}-\binom{9}{8}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is ok, but to continue, you should write it as $\binom{10}2$ rather than $\binom{10}8$

Now to exclude cases with more than $2$ of the first type, we make sure we *violate* the given condition by choosing $3$ of the first type right at the start,
and choose only $5$ more doughnuts in any which way, thus $\binom{5+3-1}{3-1} = \binom72$

The final answer is thus $\binom{10}2 - \binom72$

Comment: Isn't $\binom{10}{2} = \binom{10}{8}$?

Comment: @Stefan4024. Yes, I did mention that the two amount to the same, but in order to figure out how many cases violate the conditions, we  use $2$ for the lower index rather than $8$.

Comment: It's interchangeable to be fair, I have seen using $n$ more often to be fair.

Comment: @trueblueanil hmm,ok thank for comment and explantion  ^^

Comment: @Stefan4024: For such cases, don't you think it is better to work it out as $\binom{10}2-\binom72$ rather than $\binom{10}8 - \binom75$ ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Doesn't make any difference to be fair. Anyway nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

When we take 0 doughnuts of first type , we can simply say that the sum of number of doughnuts of other two types should be 8. So there are 9 ways possible here in case 1.

ex: If A and B are the other two types, we can assign values as number of doughnuts like if A=1, B must be 7 because the sum must be eight. We get 9 possible combinations for (A,B)

Next if we take 1 doughnut of first type, the sum of of other two types should be 7. So, 7+1 =8 possible combinations here. Next if we take 2 of first type, we get 7 possible combinations. So the total number of combinations is 7+8+9 = 24 . Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct.   I would stress that the reason there are nine solutions when $A + B = 8$ is that $A$ can assume any of the nine integer values from $0$ to $8$ and that choosing $A$ determines $B = 8 - A$.